# The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. at vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:112 on loop in log

Tags: magento2, stores, request, slow-response

Im facing this issue in magento 2.3.7 that my site is getting load in 5-10 mins. after restating the server its working fine but again in every 1 hour its going down like this when i try to look in logs.
this error is constantly hitting while loading the site when

```
The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. at /home/h1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:112)"} []
```

Please help me to get this resolve because of this site is going slow again and again in every hour .

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

It look either you have misconfiguration in stores or one of theme is causing the issue.Can you share more details on it from log file.

Answer (score 0):

It's an error in server configuration. Your server Nginx or apache 2 sends incorrect store_code to PHP. There is param `$MAGE_RUN_CODE` in the site configuration. Add `var_dump($_SERVER);` in your index.php .
You have to change store code in MySQL DB or in a site configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the correct storecode within your nginx configuration file.

Another way is to add the correct store id within your index.php file as it's leading. I would however use the nginx way, as it's recommended by my host.